# How can we interpret feature importances for Stochastic Gradient Descent Classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linearmodels, sgd

I have a SGDClassifier model trained with scikit-learn. I extract features names with `.get_feature_names()` and coefficients with `.coef_`

I combine the 2 columns in a dataframe like this :

```
feature     value
hiroshima   3.918584
wildfire    3.287680
earthquake  3.256817
massacre    3.186762
storm       3.124809
...         ...
job         -1.696438
song        -1.736640   
as          -1.956571   
nowplaying  -2.028240   
write       -2.263968
```

I want to know how I can interpret the features importances ?
What does a positive high value mean?
What does a low negative value mean?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about programming as defined in the [help] but about ML theory and/or methodology.

Answer (score 1):

SGDClassifier fits a linear model, meaning that the decision is essentially based on

```
SUM_i w_i f_i + b
```

where `w_i` is the weight attached to feature `f_i`, consequently you can interpret these numbers as literally "votes" for positive/negative class at the scale proportional to their absolute value. All that your classifier does is to add these weights, and then it adds `_intercept` value from your model, and classifies based on the sign.